# null pointer exception for onclicklistener event

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a runtime exception in my code that says :
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abiel.contacts/com.example.abiel.contacts.Data}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.relative.RelativeLayout

Here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.relative.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/ContactImage"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="294dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:hint="Please write your name"
            android:textColorHint="#ff84eb"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="296dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editNumber"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:hint="Enetr your number"
            android:textColorHint="#ff9cda"
            android:layout_above="@+id/editEmail"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="297dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editEmail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:hint="Please write your E-mail"
            android:textColorHint="#ff96ea"
            android:layout_above="@+id/save"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#ff0009"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

</android.support.relative.RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove comment from ~setContentView~ method

Comment: when I use that line I get this runtime exception                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abiel.contacts/com.example.abiel.contacts.Data}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.relative.RelativeLayout, it doesn't like my layout file not sure why I'll edit the post to show what the file looks like

Comment: post your XML code along with question

Comment: `InflateException` doesn't tell you much. Look further on in the stack trace for the root cause.

Comment: I see a class not found exception :

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.relative.RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.abiel.contacts .....       How could it not recognize relative layout

Comment: use only `RelativeLayout` instead of `<android.support.relative.RelativeLayout`, `remove android.support.relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable would not be initialized because you did not set view on Activity, you need to remove comment from `//setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);`

**Update:**
Use only `<RelativeLayout>` instead of `<android.support.relative.RelativeLayout`, remove `android.support.relative`

Answer (score 1):

As akhilesh0707  mentioned in his comment, you have removed the code to setContentView, which means that there is no layout attached to the activity. As a result, you are trying to define views without any layout to reference, so the views are not being instantiated correctly.

Simply uncommenting out the setContentView should solve your problem.